# Mongo connection has an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting while trying to connect with Cloud Atlas MongoDB. I am able to connect with my Local MongoDB, but while trying to connect with Cloud Atlas MongoDB I am facing this issue. Does anyone know what the error means? and how to resolve it.

DBConnection.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URI_Saket;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});

process.on("SIGINT", async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    process.exit(0);
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("Mongo has connected succesfully");
});
mongoose.connection.on("reconnected", () => {
    console.log("Mongo has reconnected");
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("Mongo connection has an error", error);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("Mongo connection is disconnected");
});
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const logger = require("morgan");
require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("./database/mongodbinit");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));

const allroutes = require("./routes/index");

app.use(allroutes);

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});

/** catch 404 and forward to error handler */
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  return res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: "API endpoint doesnt exist",
  });
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.message) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
  } else {
    err.message = "internal server error";
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.Port || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

MongoDB_URI

```
MONGOURI=mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.2sn1f.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I have assigned the values for DB_USER, DB_PASS and DB_NAME in .env.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t access `process.env` inside .env files.
You should write the full url with username and password.
.env is meant to be used for storing sensitive data, so its ok to put your database’s full url with credentials inside it.

another approach would be:

```
const options = {
  db: { native_parser: true },
  server: { poolSize: 5 },
  replset: { rs_name: 'yourSetName' },
  user: 'yourUserName',
  pass: 'yourPassword',
  promiseLibrary: global.Promise
}
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(conn=>{}).catch(err=>{});
```